# Comparing 2 txt files and creating a new txt file from what is absent in 1 or the files

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 2 txt files, one is a list of fruits, the other is a list of many pieces of data with a fruit embedded in each line as follows:

file 1:

```
apple
orange
grape
banana
pear
```

file 2

```
Brian b7890 apple orchard autumn
Sue c7623 grape vineyard summer
Richard z4501 grapefruit citrusGrove autumn
Mary m8123 pear orchard autumn
```

I need to extract lines from file 2 where its corresponding fruit does NOT appear in file 1 and write it into a new text file. The only line in this example of file 2 that would meet the criteria is:

```
Richard z4501 grapefruit citrusGrove autumn
```

PLEASE NOTE: I've given this example because the word 'grape' which appears in file 1 is part of the word grapefruit which would exclude some of the more simple extraction methods.

I started by putting each line of each file into lists:

```
f = open('ListOfFruits.txt')
listOfFruits = [line.strip() for line in open('ListOfFruits.txt')]
f.close()

a = open('AllFruitData.txt')
AllFruitData = [line.strip() for line in open('AllFruitData.txt')]
a.close()

i=0
x=0

while x < len(listOfFruits):
    if listOfFruits[i] not in allFruitData[x]:
        i=i+1
        #then check against allFruitData again
        #continue until the end of listOfFruits
        #if no match is found then add the line allFruitData[x] to a new txt file
   x=x+1
```

I've tried various methods using for loops while loops and if statements but always seem to get stuck with the syntax. I'm trying to imagine the code working as 2 wheels spinning against each other, whilst 1 is stationary the other spins all the way around until a match is found. If a match is found then the stationary wheel would move on 1 position and the moving wheel would reset. If the stationary wheel dosen't find a match on the moving wheel then that piece of data would go into a new basket. This would continue until all the positions on the stationary wheel have been traversed by the moving wheel.

Comment: so for every fruit in file 2, if that DOESN'T appear in file 1, you want to write that to a new file?

Comment: If you're not doing this for educational purposes, you should know you're reinventing [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) (if you substitute whitespace by newlines, at least). You should clarify if you want help understanding your algorithm or simply attaining your objective (for which there are faster, easier methods, such as using sets)

Comment: Thanks guys, yes Totem thats it, the whole line from file 2 though. goncalopp I'm ideally looking to do both. I'm quite new to writing code. This isn't for educational purposes, my actual files are nothing to do with fruit but it works well as an example to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `set`s. Then you can use [set differences](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).  A simple implementation could be (if the fruit is always in the 3rd spot in each line of your second file)

```
with open('listOfFruits.txt', 'r') as f:
    fruits = set([line.rstrip() for line in f])
with open('allFruitData.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        fruit = line.rstrip().split()[2]
        data[fruit] = line

fruits_not_in_file = set(data.keys()) - fruits
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    for fruit in fruits_not_in_lile:
        f.write(data[fruit])
```

---

**Edit:**

In the case that the fruits can appear in any column, this problem is much harder if you do not know which words are fruits.  However, if you would just like to print out the lines which contain none of your named fruits, that's not too bad:

```
with open('listOfFruits.txt', 'r') as f:
    fruits = set([line.rstrip() for line in f])

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outf, open('allFruitData.txt', 'r') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        words = set(line.rstrip().split())
        # you can replace this `if` with `if fruits & words == set()`
        if not fruits & words:
            outf.write(line)
```

What this does is first read in all the fruits as a set.  Then, for each line in the data file, we test if any of the words in that line are in the fruits set.  If the intersection is empty, then print that line out to your outfile.  If the line contains a fruit somewhere, then continue to the next line.

Note that this will not match `'grape'` with `'grapefruit'` because it splits the line based on whatever delimiter you choose (looks like space or `\t`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately in file 2 fruit can appear in any column out of 12-15 columns for my actual file

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job(assuming fruits in file2 are always the third item):

```
def compare_fruits():

    files = ["file1", "file2"]
    file_list = []

    for file in files:
        with open("filepath/%s.txt", % file "r") as f:
            file_list.append(f.readlines())

    list1 = [i.strip() for i in file_list[0]]
    list2 = [i.split()[2] for i in file_list[1]]

    diff = []

    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if j not in i:
                diff.append(j)

    with open("filepath/file3.txt", "w") as f: #creates file3 if doesn't exist
        for i in diff:
            f.write(i + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately in file 2 fruit can appear in any column out of 12-15 columns for my actual file

Comment: One real solution here would be if you had a file or list of all the fruit names you are likely to encounter inside files 1 and 2. Is this something you could do here? It would make it easy.. my original post had a solution for this. I mean, how many fruits could you really encounter?

Comment: Sounds like it could work if I had such a list. Unfortunately my actual data is not fruit, I'm just using fruit as an example for simplicity. The last edit from Bill has solved it now, thanks anyway though!